# Unable to remove limit on memory usage for PHP script

Tags: linux, php, memory

### The Situation

I am having an issue with a PHP script getting the following error message:

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 359923712) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /path/to/piwik/core/DataTable.php on line 969`

The script I'm running is: `/path/to/piwik/misc/cron/archive.sh`

I am assuming the numbers are Bytes, which means that total is approximately 360MB.

For all intents and purposes, I have increased the memory limits on the server well above 360MB, yet this is the number (give or take a byte) it consistently errors out at.

**Please note**: This question is *not* about fixing a memory leak in the script, nor about why the script itself is using so much memory. The script is part of the Piwik archiving process, so I cannot just fix any memory leaks, etc. For more info on this script and why I am increasing the memory limit, see ["How to setup auto archiving"](http://piwik.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/#toc-increase-php-memory-limit)

### The question

Given that the script is attempting to use over 360MB of memory, which I cannot change, why does it not seem possible for me to increase the amount of memory available to php on my server?

*Update 23rd June*: See "What I've tried" > "Increasing the per process memory limits of Linux" below for background... If I set `ulimit -v 1024000`, then check it with `ulimit -v` I get the correct value of '1024000'. If I run the script again, it will progress much further, but will eventually error out with the same memory limit (~360MB) having been reached. If I immediately check `ulimit -v`, it has reset to the original value of '524288'. This appears as though it may be the root cause of the issue.

---

### What I've tried

**Increasing PHP's memory_limit**

Given the php.ini file:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

I have edited that file, so the memory_limit directive reads;

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Restart Apache, and check the new value has stuck;

```
$ php -i | grep memory_limit
memory_limit => -1 => -1
```

Run the script, and get the same error.

I've also tried `1G`, `768M`, etc, all to the same result (ie; no change).

*Update 22nd June*: Based on [Vangel's help](https://serverfault.com/questions/280916/unable-to-remove-limit-on-memory-usage-for-php-script/280921#280921), I have attempted to set `post_max_size` to 20M in combination with setting `memory_limit`. Again, this has no effect.

*Update 23rd June*: Based on [olefebvre's help](https://serverfault.com/questions/280916/unable-to-remove-limit-on-memory-usage-for-php-script/282937#282937), I can confirm that the user running the script has read/write permission to the php.ini file containing the settings of `memory_limit`.

**Removing the memory limit on child processes of Apache**

I have found and edited the httpd.conf file to make sure there is no `RLimitMEM` directive.

I then used WHM's Apache Configuration > Memory Usage Restrictions to generate a restriction, which it claimed was at 1000M (and confirmed by checking httpd.conf).

Both of these resulted in no change to the script erroring at 360MB.

**Increasing the per process memory limits of Linux**

The current limits set on the system:

```
$ ulimit -m
524288

$ ulimit -v
524288
```

I have attempted to set both of these to unlimited:

```
$ ulimit -m unlimited
$ ulimit -v unlimited

$ ulimit -m
unlimited

$ ulimit -v
unlimited
```

Once again, this has resulted in absolutely no improvement in my problem.

*Update 23rd June*: I have run into a related issue here. If I set `ulimit -v 1024000`, then check it with `ulimit -v` I get the correct value of '1024000'. If I run the script again, it will progress much further, but will eventually error out with the same memory limit having been reached. If I immediately check `ulimit -v`, it has reset to the original value of '524288'. This appears as though it may be the root cause of the issue.

---

### My setup

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

$ uname -a
Linux example.com 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 17 11:30:06 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ php -i | grep "PHP Version"
PHP Version => 5.2.9

$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.0.63
Server built:   Feb  2 2011 01:25:12
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.2.0 rev5291
Server's Module Magic Number: 20020903:13
Server loaded:  APR 0.9.17, APR-UTIL 0.9.15
Compiled using: APR 0.9.17, APR-UTIL 0.9.15
Architecture:   64-bit
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Output of `$ php -i`: http://pastebin.com/EiRut6Nm

Comment: I think you edited the wrong php.ini. usually the php.ini is in /etc/php.ini.

I'm not sure that it might be there, but on all my RHEL server and CentOS server, it always was there. So why don't give it a try ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My server doesn't have a /etc/php.ini file, so definitely not there :)
As per the question, I can confirm that after editing the /usr/local/lib/php.ini file and restarting apache that the settings stick.

Comment: I am curious as to why the question received a down-vote? Is it not a [good question](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask)? If not, how can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[M. Tibbits answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/280916/unable-to-remove-limit-on-memory-usage-for-php-script/282873#282873) alludes to allowing Piwik to use more resources during the archiving process.

There is a limitation on how large an SQL command can be executed, which defaults to just 1MB. For more info; [Packet too large](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)

To increase the size limitation in MySQL, edit `/etc/my.cnf` and set `max_allowed_packet=32M`

Ensure the PHP memory limit is set to be high enough per forked process by editing `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` and set `memory_limit = 512M`

Finally, ensure all processes have at least a 1G hard limit before the system shuts them off by executing <strike>`ulimit -v 1048576`</strike> on the command line.

**Update**

`ulimit -v 1048576` will only raise the *soft* limit. If the *hard* limit is not high enough, the system will automatically reset the soft limit to that of the hard limit.

To set the hard limit, add the `-H` switch:

```
ulimit -vH 1048576
```

followed by increasing the soft limit up to this value:

```
ulimit -vS 1048576
```

Comment: I may have spoken too soon - it appears this solution does not work.

Comment: Need to up the hard limit followed by the soft limit. This was the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Background:**

I just grabbed the current version of Piwik -- In version 1.5, line 969 appears as:

```
public function addRowsFromSerializedArray( $stringSerialized )
{
    $serialized = unserialize($stringSerialized);
    if($serialized === false)
    {
        throw new Exception("The unserialization has failed!");
    }
    $this->addRowsFromArray($serialized);
}
```

and is specifically `$serialized = unserialize($stringSerialized);`.  The call to `unserialize` can be incredibly memory intensive.  There is an excellent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572939).

As you've noted, **this clearly isn't a bug in your script and is a valid Out of Memory**.

**Suggestion:** In the config file, as noted above in my comment:

`/.../piwik/config/global.ini.php`

I think you may need to increase one of these limits:

```
# during archiving, Piwik will limit the number of results recorded, for performance reasons
# maximum number of rows for any of the Referers tables (keywords, search engines, campaigns, etc.)
# this limit will also be applied to the Custom Variables names and values reports
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_referers = 1000
# maximum number of rows for any of the Referers subtable (search engines by keyword, keyword by campaign, etc.)
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_subtable_referers = 50

# maximum number of rows for any of the Actions tables (pages, downloads, outlinks)
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_actions = 500
# maximum number of rows for pages in categories (sub pages, when clicking on the + for a page category)
# note: should not exceed the display limit in Piwik_Actions_Controller::ACTIONS_REPORT_ROWS_DISPLAY
#       because each subdirectory doesn't have paging at the bottom, so all data should be displayed if possible.
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_subtable_actions = 100

# maximum number of rows for other tables (Providers, User settings configurations)
datatable_archiving_maximum_rows_standard = 500
```

where I changed the semi-colons to # signs just to make sf's autocolor readable.

You might also try adding:

```
CMD_TO_CHECK_SETTINGS="$PHP_BIN -i > /tmp/piwik-php-env.out"
$CMD_TO_CHECK_SETTINGS
```

to archive.sh to determine if there are other settings afoot which override the php.ini file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however it points out what I already know as stated in the question. Since this answer doesn't help with the actual question asked, I would like to down-vote (but don't have enough rep to do so).

Comment: A-ha! Progress!
I upped `memory_minimum_limit` to 1024, and increased the variables you listed by a factor of 10 each, and set ulimit -m and ulimit -v to 'unlimited'.
The error message I get now is `SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`
Further investigation lead me to increase mysqld's `max_allowed_packet=32M` (was previously at `1M`). Ran the script perfectly!
I will narrow it down and report back as to the exact solution :)

Comment: Final solution;
1. Edit `/etc/my.cnf` and set `max_allowed_packet=32M`. 2. Edit `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` and set `memory_limit = 512M`. 3. Set `ulimit -v 1048576`. Not sure why, but changing those settings you mentioned in piwik's config file seem to have induced the second SQL error stated above, which lead me to setting max_allowed_packet. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Spoke too soon - it now appears that the ulimit -v value is being reset, so while the script gets past the initial hurdle where it was previously failing, the ulimit -v value is reset, and the script then fails once again further along.

Comment: Without knowing precisely what/where the error message is, my initial suspicion would be that a function call is issuing a command under another user which does not have the generous `ulimit` settings you've specified.

Comment: @M.Tibbits let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/601/discussion-between-jess-telford-and-m-tibbits)

Answer (score 0):

this is definitely a script bug. It seems that there is a memory leak so no matter how much you increase the memory limit in PHP it will hit it.

I use Piwik on a basic level and dont remember ever using an archiving script directly. Piwik is a bit buggy still but the latest version is 1.4 and seems to be much less buggy that previous ones.

I recommend not to screw around with system or PHP settings for the sake of accommodating an erroneous script. Hitting the piwik support forum might be a better idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As stated in the question; this is not about fixing an error in Piwik. The strange behavior is: Given that a script uses over 360MB of memory, why can I not seem to allow it to use more?

Comment: restarted the webserver?

Comment: I have restarted Apache, if that's what you mean. It's not feasible for me to restart the entire operating system.

Comment: yes just web server. so what did you get? Also if it hasnt worked out it would be helpful to look at the phpinfo. I suspect its not picking up the ini from the place where you are modifying it? 
p.s. we are way off timezones. PM me your skype id if you can and maybe we can just chat to figure this out, then post the solution here

Comment: Let's keep it all here where possible - who knows what information might help someone else.
Output of `$ php -i`: http://pastebin.com/EiRut6Nm (edited to keep one or two details private)

Comment: Agreed on posting here. I see that
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini 
I assume this is where you are eidting?
So dont use -1 memory limit put a finite value.
Also in the post_max_size increase to say 20MB
restart webserver(important). Test script
if there is error please post the new error exactly and also the new php -i output.
let's see what happens. 
ahh yes, send the script name of piwik thats causing the problem. When you get the full error message it should usually give you the line number as well

Comment: As per the original question, yes; I am editing `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` and also trying finite values (such as 1G, 768M, etc). Increasing `post_max_size` to 20M (combined with memory_limit set to 2G) makes no difference.
Full error message: `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 359923712) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /path/to/piwik/core/DataTable.php on line 969`
The script I'm running is: `/path/to/piwik/core/misc/archive.sh`

Comment: My mistake, the script I'm running is: /path/to/piwik/misc/cron/archive.sh

Comment: Edit the file '/.../piwik/config/global.ini.php' and change:  `minimum_memory_limit = 128` to `minimum_memory_limit = 512`.  Does it complain that you're memory limit is too low?

Comment: hey Jess, Thanks for getting back. As I had guessed correctly this is a filed bug http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/766 and therefore no amount of PHP tweaking gonna help. So leave your php to optimal settings and lets see if there is a patch
more: http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?2,77831

Comment: Thanks for the links, mate. I've already reviewed them leading up to posting this question. The main point of my question is that I cannot seem to increase the memory limit on my server, regardless of if it's a piwik script that's running, or something else entirely unrelated.

Comment: sorry about that. What I am saying is that Piwik script is not a good way to test if your memory limit is working. Can you try to do this using a script in php, top of the script first line use
ini_set('memory_limit', 'xxxxM'); and see if that works.

Comment: With the following script: `<?php ini_set("memory_limit", "2G"); $str = ""; while(true) $str .= "M";?>`, I get exactly the same error message: `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 362545152) (tried to allocate 362282961 bytes) in /path/to/test.php on line 1`

Comment: I read your response above on Tibbits answer. I was going to suggest (i know quite late) to look at limits. If ulimit is your problem you can make the change permanent with either with kernel tune parameter or i you OS has this file /etc/security/limits.conf and add memlock limit to unlimited for the user that runs php/web.

Comment: I tried setting `memlock` for the user running the script in limits.conf, but it still errored out at the same memory usage value. See the accepted solution's update on hard vs soft limits for ulimit for the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the define command line option ?
php -d memory_limit=512M test.php

btw have you checked the php.ini is readable by the user running php from the commandline ?

Comment: I can confirm that the php.ini is readable by the user running php, as I am logged in as that user when editing the values within. `php -d memory_limit=512M` produces the same result as setting the value within the php.ini file.
Thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: FYI: I tried calling `php -d memory_limit=2G /path/to/test.php` with test.php containing: `<?php $str = ""; while(true) $str .= "M";?>` which resulted in the same error message: `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 362545152) (tried to allocate 362282961 bytes) in /path/to/test.php on line 1`

Answer (score 0):

The Linux per proc/user limit has nothing to do with this; the error you are getting is specifically tied to PHP.

On that note, I suspect there is ini_set directive somewhere that overwrites your limit; even if you put ini_set on top level file, the lower level file will overwrite it.

Simply run `grep -r -i "ini_set" /path/to/piwiki" and see if they are manually overwriting the limit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The output of `ack "ini_set" /path/to/piwik/ is here: http://pastebin.com/kDJHLC3e - You can see on line 47 of the output that Piwik is messing with memory_limit. After further investigation, it is simply trying to raise the value if it is too low. Hence, it is actually helping not hindering :(
Good idea, though!

Comment: Well it could be raising it too low ;) If anything var_dump($minimumMemoryLimit) to see what it's raising it to.

Comment: It was raising it to the expected value I had set in httpd.conf - thanks for the thought though :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm which config file you modified the memory limits in? Note that there are two different configs: one for PHP executed via the webserver and the second for PHP executed via the CLI.

```
~$ ls /etc/php5/
apache2  cli  conf.d
~$ ls /etc/php5/apache2/
conf.d  php.ini
~$ ls /etc/php5/cli/    
conf.d  php.ini
```

Also, if this being executed via a browser, in the same directory as where the actual script lies, create a temp.php file with the following contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Check what the `memory_limit` shows up as when you browse to that file.

Comment: The script was being run from the terminal. As stated in the question, the output of `php -i` confirms that I have set memory_limit in the correct place. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem last week, my solutiosn in CentOS rehel is

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf/hpptd.conf
```

search RLimitMEM directive delete or comented no uses this directives or if use allow 2000000 value

- save this file
- restart the service
- service httpd restart

Comment: As noted in the question, I have already tried this with no success.