# How comes PHP throws a "memory limit exhausted" when memory_limit is set to -1?

Tags: php

Recently I got a error message while executing a PHP script from the command line saying:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 40961 bytes)
```

`php -i | grep memory` shows:

```
memory_limit => -1 => -1
suhosin.memory_limit => 0 => 0
```

Which should set no limit at all?

The server is running `PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze16 with Suhosin-Patch (v0.9.32.1) (cli)`

How can this be?

Answer (score 1):

It is not wise to make PHP have no limit at all..
When your server is 32GB of memory, give it a maximum of 30GB, etc.
Try setting a positiv value instead of `-1` or `0`.

Make sure you target the right versions of PHP/php.ini,
depending on the mode you run a script there are:

`/etc/php5/apache` for apache

`/etc/php5/fpm` for fastcgi using mod_fpm

`/etc/php5/cgi` for cgi scripts

`/etc/php5/cli` for the php shell client

to take effect for changes you also need to restart:

`/etc/init.d/apache`

or

`/etc/init.d/php5-fpm`

If nothing helps yet,
check this question: [Unable to remove limit on memory usage for PHP script](https://serverfault.com/questions/280916/unable-to-remove-limit-on-memory-usage-for-php-script?rq=1)

Comment: When running a local script with `php script.php` I assume `php -i` will return the settings used (the shell client) in that case?

Comment: I'm not sure 100% but I think yes, scripts with `#!/usr/bin/php` are using the `cgi` configuration, `php -f` is using the `cli`settings.

Comment: I issued `php -i | grep ini`, so in my case it looks like it's using the `cli` settings: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli`, where memory_limit is set to -1.

Comment: I now found the solution (see my answer). Pretty dump, but a vendor script set the memory limit from unlimited down to 32M. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it, the problem was not the PHP configuration, but after running a global search I found a vendor script that set the memory limit to 32M :-/